# How to "seed" a rabbot queue

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

We have a distributed application using various Docker containers, communicating internally via RabbitMq (using Rabbot). This is all working well, including using RabbitMq as a container independent timer using message timeouts and deadlettering. Each of the containers guarantees (configures) the full topology on startup. Whichever is first will actually set it up.

However, we now need to seed our timers exactly once, when the rabbitMQ topology is first setup. Is there any way to seed a rabbitMQ queue with a message on creation, or detect if the queue already existed on the rabbitMq servers or that the configuration call resulted in creating the queue?